# How to return and search by dynamic fields in DSE Search

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I have a simple Cassandra KF:

```
create table messages (
  id varchar,
  headers map<varchar, varchar>,
  primary key (id));
```

The table gets an auto-generated Solr index. The values of the `headers` field will be around what you expect in email headers. I can see that Solr generates the following line for the headers:

```
<dynamicField indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="headers*" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
```

However, I can't see to find anything in the headers, nor get their values using Solr API. A record:

```
cassandra@cqlsh:tpb> SELECT id, headers FROM messages;

1492cc10-046d-11e6-a332-55ae2575ea1a | {'component-count': '1', 'component-type-0': 'Document-Upload', 'consumer-behalf': 'true', 'date': 'Sun Apr 17 2016 00:22:02 GMT-0700 (PDT)', 'from': '718bcc80-9def-11e5-a837-0800200c9a66@1a4de124-5761-4668-9e9d-a880aa4e6dd1', 'message-id': '1492cc10-046d-11e6-a332-55ae2575ea1a@32d2a682-af07-4108-a15a-de6f8a75e811', 'to': '"mark-watney@cool-dude"@32d2a682-af07-4108-a15a-de6f8a75e811', 'transaction-id': '14585b20-046d-11e6-a332-55ae2575ea1a'}
```

Running these two queries don't ever return me any header values (note that any URL encoding is reversed for readability):

```
...select?q=id:1492cc10-046d-11e6-a332-55ae2575ea1a&fl=id,headersconsumer-behalf&wt=json&indent=true
...select?q=id:1492cc10-046d-11e6-a332-55ae2575ea1a&fl=id,headers*&wt=json&indent=true
```

Searching by header value seems to yield no results either, e.g.

...select?q=headersdate:Sun&fl=id&wt=json&indent=true
...select?q=headersconsumer-behalf:true&fl=id&wt=json&indent=true

both return empty sets (but should match the above document).

It feels like I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what. Solr admin reports "headers*" field to exist, and be properly indexed and what not.

So, the question: how can I return and search by dynamic fields (inferred from a Cassandra map) in DSE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys in your CQL map need to be prepended with the dynamic field name:

```
1492cc10-046d-11e6-a332-55ae2575ea1a | {'headerscount': '1', 'headerstype-0': 'Document-Upload',...
```

or

```
1492cc10-046d-11e6-a332-55ae2575ea1a | {'headerscomponent-count': '1', 'headerscomponent-type-0': 'Document-Upload',...
```

It is recommended that the map name in CQL has the form '_' so that your dynamic fields then look like: 'headers_component-type-0'.

Comment: That really doesn't make any sense to me though, Cassandra knows the data is inside the 'headers' map, and the schema was created by Cassandra, so it must be able to prepend the name of the column to the name of the Solr field when submitting for indexing, no?